# NFS status: execstartpre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r error

Tags: rhel, nfs

when I run `systemctl status nfs` I see that there is an error which you can see in the image below:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I fix it please ?

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the subnet masks from `localhost` in `/etc/exports`.

`localhost/24` or `localhost/255.255.255.0` are not valid and should be `localhost` only as follows.

```
/mnt localhost(<your-nfs-export-options>)
```

If you want to export to a subnet use a valid subnet.

```
/mnt 192.168.0.0/24(<your-nfs-export-options>)
```

or

```
/mnt 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(<your-nfs-export-options>)
```

For a more detailed and full description consult `man exports`.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, but I still having another problem, can you a look at this please: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391823/rpc-port-mapper-failure-rpc-unable-to-receive-errno-connection-refused